# How can I create new UserPrincipal?

Tags: java, jsf, authentication

I want to create with JSF a Login Form which also creates a new UserPrincipal in External Context.

What do I have to do when I want to create a new UserPrincipal in External FacesContext?

I use WebSphere Application Server 8 with JSF 2.

I want to make something like this working:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Principal principal = context.getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();
```

Best Regards
Veote

Comment: Is `UserPrincipal` a managed bean or model bean? Also, what JSF version are you using?

Comment: @Luiggi: it's part of container managed security http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, I dont think we have to explicity create `UserPrincipal`.You must authenticate the user with some mechanism (like `JAAS` / `NTLM` / `SPNEGO`) so that container creates it for you in its `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` implementation